# Uber API: Specify multiple scopes while requesting or issuing a token returns Invalid Request Paramenters

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0

I know that the OAuth 2.0 specs allows to specify multiple scopes while requesting or issuing a token, but Uber doesn't like the multiple scopes.

For example:

**1) [No error]**

parameters = {

```
'response_type': 'code',
'redirect_uri': 'INSERT_ROUTE_TO_STEP_TWO',
'scope': 'profile',
```

}

Returns correct token and I can retrieve the user profile via 'https://api.uber.com/v1/me'

**2) [Error]**

parameters = {

```
'response_type': 'code',
'redirect_uri': 'INSERT_ROUTE_TO_STEP_TWO',
'scope': 'profile%20history',
```

}

Uber returns "Invalid Request Parameters". I tried 'scope': 'profile%20history' and 'scope': 'profile history'.  Both cases returns the same error.

I'm an Android developer using https://github.com/twotoasters/AndrOAuth as a test.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Scope uses space delimiters.

You should pass scope as `'scope': 'profile history'` and let the underlying http library handle the URI conversion rather than doing it explicitly by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured this out by now, but you are using a space to delimit your scope arguments and the api calls for a comma.