# Request Scope of Uber Sandbox

Tags: scope, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am exploring on the UBER APIs and I want to make an API call to the /request.

As I understand from other questions and discussions, we need to be specifying the "scope" as a query parameter when hitting the Authorization endpoint.

But I am trying to do that, I am receiving an error saying the scope is invalid.

I am using the below GET request :

https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<*ClientId*>&response_type=code&scope=request+profile +history+history_lite+places+ride_widgets+request_receipt+all_trips

And also in my dashboard I do not have the request scope enabled. Apparently as per the documentation we can 'test' the API in sandbox without enabling it .

Can anyone let me know where am I going wrong!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The mistake I was doing was using '+'. Instead leaving it as space and letting the underlying http take care fixed it.

Found it on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457242/uber-api-specify-multiple-scopes-while-requesting-or-issuing-a-token-returns-in